# Virtual Memory on Ubuntu

Tags: ram, swap

In Windows OSs, users can have virtual memory, which is called pagefile. Does the Swap partition behave the same as Window's pagefile, and how are they different? If they aren't equivalent, is there an Ubuntu equivalent to the pagefile?

Comment: check system monitor application. you will find more information

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ubuntu's equivalent to Windows' `pagefile` is called a `swap file` and serves the same purpose. A `swap partition` is the same as a `swap file`, except that it is a partition, not a file.

You can have as many `swap files/partitions` as you want in Ubuntu, and they can have arbitrary names and sizes. I think the default installation creates a swap partition until 17.04, and a swap file since 17.10, both the same size as your RAM.